# Buttons added with ajax don't have jQuery functions and CSS styles

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, wordpress, jquery-ui

I am making a Wordpress plugin with a table which lists rows from a mysql table. Each row has its "Edit" and "Delete" button. The table also has an "Add" button for adding rows to the table. For adding and editing rows I am using the jQuery dialog, along with an ajax function that displays any changes on the same page. This means that, when the page loads, the "Add" and "Edit" buttons have classes with jQuery functions attached to it, which open the UI dialog when they are clicked. Because of this, they also have a certain CSS style which jQuery automatically gives them.

However, when I add a new row, and it appears via ajax on the page, it's "Edit" button doesn't have the function attached to it, nor the CSS style. Also, when I edit an existing row, the values change, but so does the "Edit" button in the existing row, and it loses the functionality and CSS style, even though it has the same class. How can I make jQuery add the functionality and CSS style for the additionally added buttons through ajax?

Comment: You need to add click listeners after the row is added.

Answer (score -1):

Your jQuery function are only bound to elements that exist when the page is loaded for the first time, assuming you're doing all of this in $('document').load().

To bind functions to elements that are dynamically added, check this part of the jQuery docs:

[jQuery on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

This way jQuery continuously looks for elements to bind even after the page is loaded.

Comment: `Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().`

Comment: You're right. This is the section of the docs I should have linked to: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

I've updated my answer with that link instead.